# Not able to access www folder / Apache 2.4 webserver installation

Tags: apache, installation, centos8

The question relates to apache 2.4 webserver installation on centos8 system.I have been trying to access the var/www/html folder. I am successfully being able to get to var folder but as I try to change directory to www folder, it keeps saying "no such file or directory". Newbie here, if someone could please take the time to explain will be really grateful, thanks !!

```
root@localhost etc]# cd /var
    [root@localhost var]# ls
    account  adm  cache  crash  db  empty  ftp  games  gopher  kerberos  lib  local  lock  log  mail  nis  opt  preserve  run  spool  tmp  www  yp
    [root@localhost var]# cd /www
    bash: cd: /www: No such file or directory
```

Comment: try finding a basic unix / linux commandline manual, cd /www is a absolute path, you want cd www. or cd /var/www

Comment: thanks a lot , I did "cd /var/www" and it worked, thank you once again !!